# Where is the location of snort.conf

Tags: snort

I've installed Snort, but can't find the snort.conf file in both /ect/ and /usr/local/ (and don't have snort directory in these location as well)
Do you know where's the snort.conf
My version is 2.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without configure options check `/var/snort/install/snort-2.8.6` or below it. You can also run `find / -type f -name snort.conf` which will take a minute or 2.

Comment: I've found it using your find command. It's under source code folder :). Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Make use of **locate**

```
locate snort.conf
```

Comment: If it is just installed, then it won't be indexed.